# What service responsible for VPN server?

Tags: vpn, windows-8.1, windows-services

I have this VPN server on my OS and when I send my computer to sleep and return it from one, the server stops to receive incoming connections. So I reboot it and it works again. Either that or I can shutdown it in the first place.

I still want to use sleep, and I believe I could restart 1-2 services responsible for VPN host instead of restarting the computer.

So what are these services? I have tried "Routing and Remote Access" but that didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Remote access connection manager

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the built-in Windows VPN, I think that the service you need is called "IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Modules".

You should be able to find that in the services list and control it from there or from the command line.

Comment: That didn't work either.

Comment: Right, who set up the VPN and what does it connect to?

Comment: I did set up the VPN server and my friend connects to it. After my computer's sleep-restore he can't connect, unless I reboot in either the first or second place.

Answer (score 0):

On device manager, under Network Adapters option, right click the NIC card

1)Go to properties

2)Click on power management

3)Remove the option ‘allow the computer to turn off this device to save power’

it could solve the problem.

Comment: That didn't work.